# Issues Installing Ruby without sudo

Tags: ubuntu, ruby

I am migrating a website to a server that is running Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS, the website is managed through git and built using Jekyll. Jekyll is installed as ruby gem and unfortunately the server does not have ruby installed.

I attempted to install ruby to my user folder (I am not a sudoer)

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/bin/ruby && make && make install
```

and it appears to install fine, with the one warning:

```
skip installing bundle gems because of lacking zlib
```

When I execute the ruby executable, I get the following errors:

```
 $./ruby system --upgrade
    ./ruby: No such file or directory -- system (LoadError)

$./tmp/ruby-2.2.3/bin/gem install jekyll
/usr/bin/env: ruby: Permission denied

$ ./bin/ruby/bin/gem install jekyll
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    cannot load such file -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

I looked into the zlib, but could not find how to install it locally and set ruby to point to it.

When trying rvm, I found I was missing the following packages:

```
libreadline6-dev zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 autoconf libgdbm-dev libncurses5-dev automake libtool bison pkg-config libffi-dev
```

Anyone have some build experience that may help?